# Limita el tamaño en píxeles en la subida de imágenes en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy intentando limitar el tamaños de las imágenes que se van a guardar en la base de datos habrá alguna manera de hacerlo 
de momento solo guardo de esta manera no restringe el tamaño

Aqui es donde selecciono la imgen

```
        private void btn_BuscarFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string imagen = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    Foto.Image = Image.FromFile(imagen);
                    System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    Foto.Image.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    MostrarFoto(m);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              MessageBox.Show("El archivo seleccionado no es un tipo de 
              imagenválido"); 

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes la ruta a la imagen podrias conocer el size de esta analizando el archivo, no aplicas validaciones sobre la imagen o los pixes, eso no hace falta

Podrias hacer

```
 FileInfo f = new FileInfo(imagen);
 if(f.Length > 1048576){
    //se supera el limite permitido
    return;
 }
 //resto codigo
```

con `Length` tienes los bytes que pesa el archivo, en esa validacion si supera `1Mb = 1048576 byte` no dejo que se guarde